# I'm getting TabError in python3 but not in python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

It's working totally fine in python2 but getting this error in python3- "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" on statement "b=b+a". Already tried deleting spaces and checking for proper indentation.

```
def dice():
b=0
global a
a=random.randint(1,6)
    b=b+a
if(b>22):
    b=b-22 #Since 22 blocks in our board, one lap completion will result in 
a decrease of 22
#print b
return b
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are required after colon syntax, both in if statements as well as function definitions. Try this:

```
def dice():
    b=0
    global a
    a=random.randint(1,6)
    b=b+a
    if(b>22):
        b=b-22 #Since 22 blocks in our board, one lap completion will result in a decrease of 22
    #print b
    return b
```

Comment: I too thought so but wasnt sure as it's my friends code, although getting another error on doing that "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Comment: @ManasLadha Works for me on python 3.6.1. Try again now as i made an edit (a comment was badly formatted).

Comment: Thanks..! Working fine, maybe it has to do something with my text editor

Comment: @ManasLadha: It's a good idea to configure your text editor to expand all tabs to spaces (four spaces, to match PEP 8 style guidelines), and replace any tabs with spaces to prevent the problem recurring.